# Convert a data frame with many time series into a list of single variate xts

Tags: r, plyr, xts

I have a data frame of time series:

```
  X1.HK.Equity      X X2.HK.Equity    X.2 X3.HK.Equity   X.4
1   31/12/2002 38.855   31/12/2002 19.547   31/12/2002 5.011
2   02/01/2003 38.664   02/01/2003 19.547   02/01/2003 4.986
3   03/01/2003 40.386   03/01/2003 19.547   03/01/2003 4.962
4   06/01/2003 40.386   06/01/2003 19.609   06/01/2003 4.937
5   07/01/2003 40.195   07/01/2003 19.609   07/01/2003 4.937
6   08/01/2003 40.386   08/01/2003 19.547   08/01/2003 4.912
```

I want to take this time series and change it to a list of 3 items, each being an XTS created from columns 1-2, 3-4 and 5-6.  Note that the time series do not necessarily have the same dates.

I would be extra happy if someone could show me how to do this with using the `plyr` library.

`dput` of my data frame:

```
structure(list(X1.HK.Equity = c("31/12/2002", "02/01/2003", "03/01/2003", 
"06/01/2003", "07/01/2003", "08/01/2003"), X = c(38.855, 38.664, 
40.386, 40.386, 40.195, 40.386), X2.HK.Equity = c("31/12/2002", 
"02/01/2003", "03/01/2003", "06/01/2003", "07/01/2003", "08/01/2003"
), X.2 = c(19.547, 19.547, 19.547, 19.609, 19.609, 19.547), X3.HK.Equity = c("31/12/2002", 
"02/01/2003", "03/01/2003", "06/01/2003", "07/01/2003", "08/01/2003"
), X.4 = c(5.011, 4.986, 4.962, 4.937, 4.937, 4.912)), .Names = c("X1.HK.Equity", 
"X", "X2.HK.Equity", "X.2", "X3.HK.Equity", "X.4"), row.names = c(NA, 
6L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With plyr, using llply

```
tss = llply(c(1,3,5),function(s){ts=mydf[,s:(s+1)];xts(ts[,2],order.by=as.Date(ts[,1],format="%d/%m/%Y"))} )
```

gives you

```
> tss[[1]]
             [,1]
2002-12-31 38.855
2003-01-02 38.664
2003-01-03 40.386
2003-01-06 40.386
2003-01-07 40.195
2003-01-08 40.386
> class(tss[[1]])
[1] "xts" "zoo"
>
```

That 1,3,5 vector is more generally `seq(1,ncol(mydf),by=2)`

Answer (score 2):

An ordinary `lapply` would work here:

```
to.xts <- function(i) as.xts(read.zoo(DF[i+0:1], format = "%d/%m/%Y"))
lapply(seq(1, ncol(DF), 2), to.xts)
```

If this is not just an example and, in fact, there are only three series it would be sufficient to replace the last line with:

```
list(to.xts(1), to.xts(3), to.xts(5))
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this is the most efficient way to do this, but hopefully, it is fairly logical.

```
library(xts)
lapply(seq_along(mydf[c(FALSE, TRUE)]), function(x) {
  xts(mydf[c(FALSE, TRUE)][x], 
      order.by=as.Date(mydf[c(TRUE, FALSE)][, x], format = "%d/%m/%Y"))
})
# [[1]]
#                 X
# 2002-12-31 38.855
# 2003-01-02 38.664
# 2003-01-03 40.386
# 2003-01-06 40.386
# 2003-01-07 40.195
# 2003-01-08 40.386
# 
# [[2]]
#               X.2
# 2002-12-31 19.547
# 2003-01-02 19.547
# 2003-01-03 19.547
# 2003-01-06 19.609
# 2003-01-07 19.609
# 2003-01-08 19.547
# 
# [[3]]
#              X.4
# 2002-12-31 5.011
# 2003-01-02 4.986
# 2003-01-03 4.962
# 2003-01-06 4.937
# 2003-01-07 4.937
# 2003-01-08 4.912
```

Basically, it uses recycling of `TRUE` and `FALSE` to select alternate columns. The `seq_along` part tells us how many pairs we have (in this example, 3), and in the anonymous function, we subset the values with `c(FALSE, TRUE)`, and the dates with `c(TRUE, FALSE)`.

Comment: If your data are large, you might do better creating subsets of `mydf` outside of your `lapply` function, since (I think) this is subsetting within each "loop" that `lapply` makes.